# Riverpod FutureProvider provides AsyncValue Dependency Injection not possible

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dependency-injection, provider, riverpod

I have an abstract class `LectureRepository` implemented by `LectureRepositoryImpl`. `LectureRepositoryImpl` initialises `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences` with

```
LectureLocalDataSourceImpl({@required this.sharedPreferences})
```

Now I want to use Riverpod to access the repository so I do:

```
    FutureProvider<LectureLocalDataSource>(
  (ref) async {
    return LectureLocalDataSourceImpl(sharedPreferences: await SharedPreferences.getInstance());
  },
);
```

but now in `lectureRepositoryProvider`, wenn I read the `lectureLocalDataRepositoryProvider` I get an AsyncValue in the value `localDataSource`, which I cannot assign here:

```
final lectureRepositoryProvider = FutureProvider<LectureRepository>((ref) async {
  final localDataSource = ref.read(lectureLocalDataRepositoryProvider);
  return LectureRepositoryImpl(localDataSource: localDataSource);
});
```

How should I handle the AsyncValue?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.data` on the AsyncValue, which gives you the underlying data value.  If you need to distinguish loading vs data vs error, the AsyncValue doc will explain how.

EDIT: for riverpod 2, the proper call is `.requireData`, which will either give you data, or will *throw* if in error or loading state.

Answer (score 1):

I made if work like this, for a theme persistent with `SharedPreferences`:

```
final sharedPreferences =
    FutureProvider((ref) => SharedPreferences.getInstance());

final themeChangeNotifier = ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeChangeNotifier>((ref) {
  final prefs = ref.watch(sharedPreferences)?.data?.value;
  return ThemeChangeNotifier(prefs);
});
```

and use it like this:

```
 final isDartTheme = watch(themeChangeNotifier).isDarkTheme;
    final prefs = watch(sharedPreferences);
    return prefs.when(
      loading: () => Material(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
      data: (_) => MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: isDartTheme ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
        home: SearchPage(),
      ),
      error: (_, __) => SizedBox.shrink(),
    );
```

Gonna publish a video and the repo in a couple of days I hope :)